# When is an ng-if evaluated?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
<div class="gridRow"
        ng-click="phs.phrasesRowClicked(row)"
        ng-repeat="row in phs.phrasesView">
        xx{{ row.current }} yy
    <div ng-if="row.current">
        ABC
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!row.current">
        DEF
    </div>
</div>
```

When I view this then I see all "ABC"

When I click on a row then the value of the current property changes to TRUE and the word between xx and yy also changes to TRUE.  However the row does not change.  Everything still displays "ABC"

Here's how the row is being set to TRUE of FALSE:

```
if (phrase.phraseId == phraseId) {
    phrase.current = true;
    self.phrase = phrase;
} else {
    phrase.current = false;
}
```

Can someone tell me if I am using ng-if incorrectly?

Comment: The code is set to show ABC when `row.current` is true. If the value starts out as true (or truthy) then it works as expected. You'll have to show a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All the rows show xxfalseyy when retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are using `ng-if` correctly. If you are seeing the word `TRUE` in capitals, then my suspicion is that `row.current` is being set to the *string* `TRUE` or `FALSE` which are always evaluated as true.

Comment: I updated the question to show how current is being set to TRUE or FALSE